# Shopify API: Retrieve Orders with a specific DiscountCode

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify, shopify-api

I am currently working on a project that creates Discount Codes via API and I need to retrieve which orders have used a specified Discount Code (ex: TESTCODE123). I couldn't find the documentation or API endpoint mentioned in the Shopify API pages. Is it possible to guide me on this?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use Admin GraphQL for this and rely on the query parameter to filter them out.

Example:

```
{
  orders(first: 10, query:"discount_code:TESTCODE123"){
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can refer the docs here: [https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/queryroot?api[version]=2020-01](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/queryroot?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-01)

Comment: Is it possible with REST?

Comment: @Learner no. The REST API doesn't accept a discount field to filter by. You can reffer the docs for full details: https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order#index-2020-01